# How to create Floating IP and use it to configure HAProxy

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, floating-ip

I have recently tried to load balance my application using HAProxy and was able to do it successfully. Later, I have come across a concept called Floating IP, which can be used along with keepalived to make the load balancer highly available. I wasn't able to understand how to create the floating Ip though. How can I create Floating IP and use it to configure HAProxy?
Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

Assumptions:

- This works on Ubuntu 14.04
- haproxy-primary IP:   198.51.100.10
- haproxy-secondary IP: 198.51.100.20
- shared IP:            198.51.100.50
- Any DNS rules should point to the shared IP (198.51.100.50)

Steps:

1. Add a firewall rule for keepalived # 224.0.0.18 is the keepalived multicast address

   1. `sudo ufw allow in from 198.51.100.20 to 224.0.0.18`  # on 198.51.100.10
   2. `sudo ufw allow in from 198.51.100.10 to 224.0.0.18`  # on 198.51.100.20
2. Allow access to a shared IP address

   1. edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`
   2. set `net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind=1`
   3. `sudo sysctl -p`  # reload config change
3. Install keepalived

   1. `sudo apt-get install keepalived`
4. Configure keepalived on both servers

   1. Edit/create `/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf`
   2. See example file below # the priority MUST be different on the primary and secondary servers!
5. Restart keepalived

   1. sudo service keepalived restart
6. Listen on the shared IP address

   1. Edit `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg`
   2. `bind 198.51.100.50:80`
7. Restart haproxy (on both haproxy servers)

   1. `sudo service haproxy restart`
8. Verify proper failover

   1. primary: `sudo ip addr show | grep eth0` # should list the shared IP
   2. secondary: `sudo ip addr show | grep eth0` # should NOT list the shared IP
   3. primary: `sudo service haproxy stop`
   4. primary: `sudo ip addr show | grep eth0` # should NOT list the shared IP
   5. secondary: `sudo ip addr show | grep eth0` # should list the shared IP
   6. primary: `sudo service haproxy start`
   7. primary: `sudo ip addr show | grep eth0` # should list the shared IP
   8. secondary: `sudo ip addr show | grep eth0` # should NOT list the shared IP

## /etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf

```
     vrrp_script chk_haproxy {      # Requires keepalived-1.1.13
       script "killall -0 haproxy"  # cheaper than pidof
       interval 2 # check every 2 seconds
       weight 2 # add 2 points of priority if OK
     }
     vrrp_instance VI_1 {
       interface eth0
       state MASTER
       virtual_router_id 51
       priority 101 # 101 on primary, 100 on secondary
       virtual_ipaddress {
         198.51.100.50
       }
       track_script {
         chk_haproxy
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [Matt Rice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6510524/matt-rice) is excellent, but be aware that if you're running SELinux enforcing on Red Hat EL 7, you'll need

```
sudo setsebool haproxy_connect_any on
```

...or haproxy will fail to start on the system that does not currently have the virtual ipaddress, with a complaint that it can't bind.