# Is it possible to use haproxy as backup of haproxy?

Tags: backup, load-balancing, haproxy

I have two HAProxy in different regions. Each haproxy have some instances for balancing.

Is it possible to use each of these proxies as a backup for another?

I found this article with examples:

https://www.haproxy.com/blog/failover-and-worst-case-management-with-haproxy/

I tried to use something like this:

```
...
backend bk_app_backup
  server second_haproxy.com x.x.x.x:443 check backup
```

But I got `502 Bad Gateway` when I try to open `https://x.x.x.x`

Or, I can not use haproxy as a backup and should add all instances from `backend` of first haproxy config to second in `backup` section?

Something like this:

```
#first haproxy
...
backend http_back
  balance roundrobin
  server instance_a_01 x.x.x.x:443 check
  server instance_a_01 x.x.x.x:443 check

#second haproxy
...
backend http_back
  balance roundrobin
  server instance_b_01 x.x.x.x:443 check
  server instance_b_02 x.x.x.x:443 check
...
backend bk_app_backup
  server instance_a_01 x.x.x.x:443 check backup
  server instance_a_02 x.x.x.x:443 check backup
```

Comment: The behavior you describe doesn't match the config. In fact, I'm not aware that a backup haproxy can be implemented in haproxy configs itself. This is usually solved with keepalived and floating IPs.

People asked this before so you might want to check it out, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38086336/2670428)

Comment: Yes, I know about `keepalived`, but it requires both haproxies in the same network. My haproxis are in different netowrk zones.